# Remove All Repositories - CentOS (Can't Download Normal Stuff Anymore)

Tags: linux, centos, yum, installation, repository

Any time I do `yum install ___`, what used to be normally accessible is no longer so.

I think it is because of an installed repository causing the issue.

How do I remove all repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning yum.

```
clean [ packages | headers | metadata | cache | dbcache | all ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing all of them is a bad idea. Try selectively disabling them using the `--disablerepo=` switch. You can use that switch multiple times to remove several repos, or you can combine it with the `--enablerepo=` to create a white list.

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="rpmforge" install blahblahblah
```

That'll enable only rpmforge.

Run `yum repolist` for a list of your repositories.